# Nginx shows 2 different statuses in the upstream response log

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, nginx-log

I am running an nginx-ingress controller in a kubernetes cluster and one of my log statements for the request looks like this:

```
upstream_response_length: 0, 840
upstream_response_time: 60.000, 0.760
upstream_status: 504, 200
```

I cannot quite understand what does that mean? Nginx has a response timeout equal to 60 seconds, and tries to request one more time after that (successfully) and logs both requests?

P.S. Config for log format:

```
log-format-upstream: >-
      {
      ...
      "upstream_status": "$upstream_status",
      "upstream_response_length": "$upstream_response_length",
      "upstream_response_time": "$upstream_response_time",
      ...
      }
```

Comment: Would you please show your configs?

Answer (score 2):

According to [`split_upstream_var`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/28793092e779f7cb66504a0e41db1fce2f93d91e/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/util/split.lua#L24) method of [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx), it [splits](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/f6c2f5fb974b496dbd58f3501df93aba226c708d/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/balancer/sticky.lua#L75) results of `nginx` [health checks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_hc_module.html).

Since `nginx` can have [several upstreams](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#example), your log could be  interpreted this way:

1. First upstream is dead (504)

```
upstream_response_length: 0 // responce from dead upstream has zero length
upstream_response_time: 60.000 // nginx dropped connection after 60sec
upstream_status: 504 // responce code, upstream doesn't answer
```

2. Second upstream works (200)

```
upstream_response_length: 840 // healthy upstream returned 840b 
upstream_response_time: 0.760 // healthy upstream responced in 0.760
upstream_status: 200 // responce code, upstream is ok
```

P.S. JFYI, here's a cool HTTP headers state diagram

[image: Http-headers-status]

Comment: I guess it's really just one upstream for nginx ingress controller, which is a service in kubernetes. Is it possible that nginx just does another request to upstream when the first is dropped after 60 seconds?